# How to pass webservice parameters as JSON object?

Tags: android, json, web-services

New to Android, webservice call return status code 400. I doubt that it is due to incorrect way of passing parameters. I need to pass them as JSON object but not sure how can I do that?

Below should be the parameters and is working correctly.

[image]

In my Android code, its showing status code 400.

(Updated code as below)

```
    RequestParams params = new RequestParams();


    Map<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>(); 
map.put("login", "WT"); map.put("password", "03"); 
params.put("query", map); params.put("includeUserMiscInfo", "true");

client.post("http://XXXX/SDService_SAFTI/ServiceSD.svc/LoginUser",params,new AsyncHttpResponseHandler() {
```

I also tried using JSON object as below.

```
protected void sendJson(final String email, final String pwd) {
        Thread t = new Thread() {

            public void run() {
                Looper.prepare(); //For Preparing Message Pool for the child Thread
                HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
                HttpConnectionParams.setConnectionTimeout(client.getParams(), 10000); //Timeout Limit
                HttpResponse response;
                JSONObject json = new JSONObject();

                try {
                    HttpPost post = new HttpPost("http://192.168.0.102/SDService_SAFTI/ServiceSD.svc/LoginUser");
                    Query queryObj = new Query();
                    queryObj.setLogin("WT");
                    queryObj.setPassword("3");


                    json.put("Query", queryObj);
//                  json.put("email", email);
//                  json.put("password", pwd);
                    json.put("includeUserMiscInfo", true);


                    StringEntity se = new StringEntity( json.toString());
                    se.setContentType(new BasicHeader(HTTP.CONTENT_TYPE, "application/json"));
                    post.setEntity(se);
                    response = client.execute(post);

                    /*Checking response */
                    if(response!=null){


                        InputStream in = response.getEntity().getContent(); //Get the data in the entity
                         Toast.makeText(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), "Response:" + convertStreamToString(in),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                    }

                } catch(Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
//                  getActivity().createDialog("Error", "Cannot Estabilish Connection");
                }

                Looper.loop(); //Loop in the message queue
            }
        };

        t.start();
    }

    private static String convertStreamToString(InputStream is) {

        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

        String line = null;
        try {
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                sb.append((line + "\n"));
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            try {
                is.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        return sb.toString();
    }
```

But it returned - Request Error xml

Any suggestions are welcome. Many thanks in advance.

Comment: My problem got resolved here --> http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35738165/passing-json-obj-as-parameter-in-webservice-returns-bad-request-response/35738591#35738591

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure your url `http://192.168.0.102/DService/ServiceSD.svc/LoginUser?Query=login=WT&password=03&includeUserMiscInfo=true` is correct?

Comment: http://192.168.0.102/XXXXXXX/XXXXSD.svc/LoginUser is correct. I am not sure how to pass the parameters? I tried using Requestparams too. Pls see advanced client url (Correct).

Comment: Your updated code looks correct. Do you still get 400 error or something else (any errors in logcat)?

Comment: Still same status code = 400. Bad request. No error on Android Monitor.

Comment: Have a look at https://loopj.com/android-async-http/doc/com/loopj/android/http/RequestParams.html You might need combine some approaches

Comment: Map<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
    map.put("login", "WT");
    map.put("password", "03");
    params.put("user", map); // url params: "user[first_name]=James&user[last_name]=Smith"

    params.put("query", map);
    params.put("includeUserMiscInfo", "true");

Answer (score 0):

You can use below method to call your web service:

```
public void makeHTTPCall() {

        RequestParams params = new RequestParams();
        String query = "[login=WT&password=03]"
        params.put("query", query);
        params.put("includeUserMiscInfo", "true");

        prgDialog.setMessage(getResources().getString(R.string.please));
        AsyncHttpClient client = new AsyncHttpClient();

        client.post("http://192.168.0.102/SDService_SAFTI/ServiceSD.svc/LoginUser",
                params, new AsyncHttpResponseHandler() {

            @Override
            public void onSuccess(String response) {
                // Hide Progress Dialog
                prgDialog.hide();       

// do your code if result is success

            }


            @Override
            public void onFailure(int statusCode, Throwable error,
                    String content) {

                prgDialog.hide();

                if (statusCode == 404) {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                            "Requested resource not found",
                            Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }

                else if (statusCode == 500) {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                            "Something went wrong at server end",
                            Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }

                else {
                    Toast.makeText(
                            getApplicationContext(),
                            getResources().getString(R.string.some_error_occured)
                            , Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                            .show();
                }
            }
        });
    }
```

Hope this will help you.

Comment: KishuDroid, see the screenshot. My webservices parameters are not that straightforward. Query got 2 items inside - login and password. Then includeUserMiscInfo is another parameter.

Comment: Actually the format you are passing is incorrect. So try to pass it like this. See my edit

Comment: I used exactly the one you mentioned:  RequestParams params = new RequestParams();
        String query = "[login=WT&password=03]"
        params.put("query", query);
        params.put("includeUserMiscInfo", "true");

Comment: params.put("user", map); 
params.put("query", map); what is this.

Comment: Srry params.put("user", map);  was extra. Updated the code. But still same error.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/104961/discussion-between-kishudroid-and-dep).