# Passing JSON obj as parameter in webservice - returns "Bad Request" response

Tags: android, json, web-services

New to Android, I need to use below parameters in my webservices call. I understand that parameters are actually JSON objects.

[image]

Below code returns XML with "title: Bad request" when it should return logged in user info. logcat is showing value as --> json: {"Query":"com.androidatc.customviewindrawer.Query@f1eb09f","includeUserMiscInfo":true} means my parameter is not correct. How to pass it correctly?

```
protected void sendJson(final String email, final String pwd) {
        Thread t = new Thread() {

            public void run() {
                Looper.prepare(); //For Preparing Message Pool for the child Thread
                HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
                HttpConnectionParams.setConnectionTimeout(client.getParams(), 10000); //Timeout Limit
                HttpResponse response;
                JSONObject json = new JSONObject();

                try {
                    HttpPost post = new HttpPost("http://192.168.0.102/SDService_SAFTI/ServiceSD.svc/LoginUser");
                    Query queryObj = new Query();
                    queryObj.setLogin("WT");
                    queryObj.setPassword("3");


                    json.put("Query", queryObj);
//                  json.put("email", email);
//                  json.put("password", pwd);
                    json.put("includeUserMiscInfo", true);


                    StringEntity se = new StringEntity( json.toString());
                    se.setContentType(new BasicHeader(HTTP.CONTENT_TYPE, "application/json"));
                    post.setEntity(se);
                    response = client.execute(post);

                    /*Checking response */
                    if(response!=null){


                        InputStream in = response.getEntity().getContent(); //Get the data in the entity
                         Toast.makeText(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), "Response:" + convertStreamToString(in),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                    }

                } catch(Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
//                  getActivity().createDialog("Error", "Cannot Estabilish Connection");
                }

                Looper.loop(); //Loop in the message queue
            }
        };

        t.start();
    }

    private static String convertStreamToString(InputStream is) {

        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

        String line = null;
        try {
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                sb.append((line + "\n"));
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            try {
                is.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        return sb.toString();
    }
```

Query.java

```
public class Query {
    String login;

    public void setPassword(String password) {
        this.password = password;
    }

    public void setLogin(String login) {
        this.login = login;
    }

    String password;

    public String getPassword() {
        return password;
    }

    public String getLogin() {
        return login;
    }




}
```

Any suggestions are appreciated. Many thanks in advance.

Comment: I've updated my answer try like that. But don't copy and paste because i wrote that directly in Editor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As your Json Type, you may have to do like this,

```
JSONArray array = new JSONArray();
array.put("login=WT&password=3");

json.put("Query", array);
json.put("includeUserMiscInfo", "true");
```

I want to suggest you to try replacing this line too,

```
json.put("includeUserMiscInfo", true);
```

**with**

```
json.put("includeUserMiscInfo", "true");
```

Comment: This worked! Many thanks for your help, greatly appreciate it. Was stuck in this for 3 days.

Answer (score 1):

I think that you have some confuses when you add entity for HTTPPOST.
You need to send a JSONArray Object, but in fact, you sent a JSon Object.
Please see the image: http://prntscr.com/aa49cj

Comment: May be you are right, how can I pass JSONArray Object?

Answer (score 0):

Reason is you are not passing key, just passing value. It should be

```
somekey = your JSON
```

by using `somekey` you can access your `JSON` from Web API

Comment: what is somekey? Can you explain further. tks.

Comment: `somekey` is any key, data should be send in key-value pair where `somekey` can be anything of your choice

Comment: Added Query.java also in the code. Pls see if this is what you mean?

Comment: you are not getting my point. Data should be send like `userName=Dep, field=android`. In that manner it should be in key-value pair

Comment: I got your point. logcat is showing value as --> json: {"Query":"com.androidatc.customviewindrawer.Query@f1eb09f","includeUserMiscInfo":true} means my parameter is not correct. But how to pass it correctly?